# Findwindow does not work in 64bit VBA7

Tags: excel, vba, 64-bit

The code presented at [Unlocking Password Protected VBA project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30508341/unlocking-password-protected-vba-project/30604345#30604345) works under 32 but not 64bit.
Specifically,

```
Ret = FindWindow(vbNullString, "VBAProject Password")
```

always return 0. I have tried

```
Ret = FindWindow("#32770", "VBAProject Password")

Ret = FindWindow("XLMAIN", "VBAProject Password")
```

None works. I have also tried the following APIs: setforegroundwindow, bringwindowtotop, setfocus, getactivewindow, getwindowthreadprocessid. Still failed so I don't think it's a focus issue. Perhaps it's timing? I tried using

```
SetTimer
```

but I am new to APIs so not sure how to implement that.

I am calling this via the workbookopen app event inside my personal.xlsb I am trying to fill in password upon opening any workbook.

```
Private Sub AppEvent_WorkbookOpen(ByVal wb As Excel.Workbook)

If wb.VBProject.Protection <> 1 Then
Exit Sub
End If

Call unlockvba(wb)

End Sub
```

Edit: I have set my declarations to PtrSafe and LongPtr where applicable.

Comment: Found this. http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=174982 Apparently, findwindow doesn't work because the password dialogbox is modal. Seems a timer is needed but not sure how to implement one :/

Comment: [Interesting Read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174469/unprotect-vbproject-from-vb-code/16176557#16176557) :P

Comment: @SiddharthRout DUDE. I KNOW. That's where it all started. My link above  to the other question links to your site so I didn't link it again here XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. The issue wasn't 64bit, it was a timing/focus issue.

```
Sub unlockVBA(wb)

If wb.name = "PERSONAL.XLSB" Then Exit Sub

Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = True

TimerID = SetTimer(0&, 0&, 500&, AddressOf TimerProc)

Application.VBE.CommandBars(1).FindControl(ID:=2578, recursive:=True).Execute

End Sub

Public Sub TimerProc(ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal wMsg As LongPtr, ByVal idEvent As LongPtr, ByVal dwTime As LongPtr)

On Error Resume Next
KillTimer hwnd, TimerID

MyPassword = "password"

Ret = FindWindow(vbNullString, "VBAProject Password")
ChildRet = FindWindowEx(Ret, ByVal 0&, "Edit", vbNullString)
If ChildRet <> 0 Then
Call SendMessage(ChildRet, WM_SETTEXT, False, ByVal MyPassword)
DoEvents
End If

ChildRet = FindWindowEx(Ret, ByVal 0&, "Button", vbNullString)

If ChildRet <> 0 Then
'MsgBox "Button's Window Found"

'~~> Get the caption of the child window
strBuff = String(GetWindowTextLength(ChildRet) + 1, Chr(0))
GetWindowText ChildRet, strBuff, Len(strBuff)
ButCap = strBuff

'~~> Loop through all child windows
Do While ChildRet <> 0
    '~~> Check if the caption has the word "OK"
    If InStr(1, ButCap, "OK") Then
    '~~> If this is the button we are looking for then exit
    OpenRet = ChildRet
    Exit Do
    End If

    '~~> Get the handle of the next child window
    ChildRet = FindWindowEx(Ret, ChildRet, "Button", vbNullString)
    '~~> Get the caption of the child window
    strBuff = String(GetWindowTextLength(ChildRet) + 1, Chr(0))
    GetWindowText ChildRet, strBuff, Len(strBuff)
    ButCap = strBuff
Loop

If OpenRet <> 0 Then
'~~> Click the OK Button
SendMessage ChildRet, BM_CLICK, 0, vbNullString
Else
MsgBox "The Handle of OK Button was not found"
End If
Else
MsgBox "Button's Window Not Found"
End If
```