# Unlock protected VBA Project Excel 2013

Tags: excel, passwords, vba

I am attempting to unlock a VBA Project that is password protected and have not had any luck so far. I have tried opening the vbaproject.bin part of the file in a hex editor and replacing the "DPB" line but that has not worked. I have seen this question on other forums but most of the answers provided only seemed to work with the older versions of Excel so I was curious if anyone had had any success in unlocking a VBA project on the newer version of Excel.

Comment: Any reason you used newer instead of just stating what version? O.o

Comment: I apologize, Excel 2013 is the version I am using.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272503/how-do-i-remove-the-password-from-a-vba-project

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026483/is-there-a-way-to-crack-the-password-on-an-excel-vba-project

Comment: Thanks MatthewD, but I've tried those methods already and many of those suggestions are for older versions.

Comment: Sid has a very clever hack by swapping memory address. It's on SO. Search for it.

Comment: Yea saw his solution. Didn't have any luck with it. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174469/unprotect-vbproject-from-vb-code/16176557#16176557

Comment: Then take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30628817/findwindow-does-not-work-in-64bit-vba7)

Answer (score 1):

I saved my .xlsm as a .xls file. Then I edited the file at http://www.onlinehexeditor.com/, by replacing PDB by PDx by replacing the B=62 hex by x=78 hex.

See more in [How do I remove the password from a VBA project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272503/how-do-i-remove-the-password-from-a-vba-project)

Finally, I saved as .xlsm again and it worked out for me.